# Judaism and dementia

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books, choleh-sick, psych-mentalhealth

Are there any books/articles that discuss dementia from a Jewish perspective? I am looking for a perspective that include coping with, and relevant hashkafa. The intended audience being not the sick person, but family.

It is possible that a book for family members of the terminally sick would be applicable; ideally it would include the mentally degenerative aspect of dementia.

May we never know such things.

Comment: There is a book written by Douglas J. Kohn called Broken Fragments: Jewish Experiences of Alzheimer's Disease through Diagnosis, Adaptation and Moving On. I do not think it is from a Orthodox perspective, however it is from a Jewish perspective.

Comment: The Talmud teaches us to respect a Talmid Chacham even after he forgets his learning; this is derived from the broken Luchot that were preserved.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very informative *shiur* with Rabbi Torczyner on [YUTorah about dementia](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/814506/rabbi-mordechai-torczyner/medical-halachah-judaism-and-dementia-care/).

Additionally, a book titled [A Jewish Response to Dementia](http://www.jewishlights.com/page/product/JL35) by Rabbi Cary Kozberg, is particularly useful for families that seek understanding, instruction and comfort regarding dementia care.

Answer (score 1):

there's an excellent book in hebrew called Etzot v'Hadrachot by Yaakov Greenwald based on a correspondance with the Steipler zt'l.
according to the first page, author lives on 2 sylvan road monsey, NY 10952